# Observable.forEach what happened to error and completed callback?

Tags: rxjs, observable

I saw an interesting video from 2018 about rxjs and observables
and I was wondering what happened to Observable.forEach
It seems to have been changed quite a lot.
What happened to return type subscription? Now it is a Promise and forEach does not accept
any callback functions for handling errors or completed event?

[[image]

image from https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/asynchronous-javascript-rxjs-observables/table-of-contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Observable.forEach` won't emit any `next` after an error [since RxJS 6.3.0](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-9).

> Observable: forEach will no longer next values after an error (b4bad1f)

You can handle `error` and `complete` notifications by `then()` or `catch()` because `forEach` returns a Promise.

```
range(1, 10).forEach(console.log)
  .then(() => console.log('Promise resolved'))
  .catch(() => console.log('Promise rejected'));
```

But yes, there's no way to unsubscribe when using `forEach` until the source errors or completes.